# How can a Perl script detect if it is running within the Komodo IDE?

Tags: perl, detection, komodo-ide

One way I found is to check if the Perl Debugger is "loaded" by checking for *defined($DB::single)* and assuming Komodo is active, if $DB::single is defined..

But this might also mean the script is legitimately running as *perl -d*  under the "standalone" debugger.

```
#!/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.10/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say switch/;

# detect debugger ..
SayDebugerStatus();
sub SayDebugerStatus {
   print "Debugger ";
   given ($DB::single) {
      when (undef) {
         say "not loaded.";
      }
      when (0) {
         say "loaded but inactive";
      }
      default {
         say "loaded and active";
      }
   }
   return defined($DB::single) ? 1:0;
}
```

---

**zakovyrya**'s suggestion leads to:

```
if ( grep( /.*Komodo\ IDE\.app/g,  values %INC) ){
    say "Komodo is running"
} else {
   say "Komodo is not running"
};
```

But is there another way?

---

**UPDATE** today my isKomodo() routine failed. Some investigation showed, that IT changed my global path settings from "long" to "short" names (this is under Windows) .. there nolonger is a "KOMODO" string in the %INC hash..

I'm looking for a replacement.

Comment: May I ask why you need to do this?

Comment: I want to write to the "output" window (aka StdOut) when in the IDE and to a log file when running outside. (to lazzy to do it with startup options <g>)

Comment: And what does "outside" mean? Manually from the shell, via cron-job, etc?

Comment: yes, "Not within Komodo is outside (Komodo)" is what I meant!

Comment: Sure. But I was thinking that you could maybe try to detect if you are run from a shell. If not, you could conclude that Komodo is doing the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your %INC contain when you launch script under Komodo? There is a good chance that some Komodo-specific modules are loaded.
It's better to print its content with:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%INC;
```

Comment: +1 **that works**, see my edited question ... but since "%INC" is external (based on environment) I still hope there might be another way to detect Komodo.

Comment: You will need something external. Komodo could hardly influence something internal.

Comment: as I showed above, it already loads the debugger without my doing (kind-of) .. it might load something else that is identifiable..

Answer (score 2):

Seems like something like this is easier (for the script to know it's running under Komodo):

```
use Modern::Perl;
if (exists $ENV{'KOMODO_VERSION'}) {
   say "Script is running under Komodo $ENV{'KOMODO_VERSION'} !";
} else {
   say "script is not running in Komodo"
}
```

UPDATE(by 'lexu): KOMODO (7) now places KOMODO_VERSION in the environment

Comment: My guess is, that $KOMODO_VERSION is new in Komodo 6 .. and yes, using that is much easier ..